# Pass variable to another class

Tags: c#, uwp

I have one xaml.cs file where I receive lat and lon and write it to variables.
Like this

```
     public async void WeatherDisplay()
            {

                try
                {
                    //var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
                    var geoLocator = new Geolocator();

                    Geoposition pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                     lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                     lon = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
 catch
            {

            }
        }
```

I need to pass this values to another .cs file and write them to DB

Here is code for writing to DB.

```
 public class CreatingBD
    {
        private string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
        public void  Create()
        {
            SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
            conn.CreateTable<DataForWeather>();
            conn.Insert(new DataForWeather()
            {
                lat = WeatherDisplay,
                lon = lonParam
            });
        }

        public class DataForWeather
        {
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Where `lat` and `lon` is those variables.

Thank's for help.

Comment: Read up on dependency inversion.

Comment: Before pass these values to another class make sure your declared class has **public** method

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Methods can take parameters. Have create take a lat and long as parameters.

```
public void Create(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    // code removed for brevity
   double lon = longitude;
   double lat = latitude;
}
```

Comment: I don't understood how to write code. I edited my post

Comment: You don't know how to change a method to take parameters exactly as shown in the examples in two different solutions?

Comment: Yes, I don't know

Comment: I feel like this question should be deleted, you should take a class on programming, or read an article on how to copy and paste or something. Then if you still don't get it maybe try your hand at baking or something instead.